# Is there a library/module like pymem for/in Julia?

Tags: memory, julia

I need to be able to read and modify memory in Julia. Is there a library for that or any other way to do this?

Comment: >A python library to manipulate Windows processes (32 and 64 bits). With pymem you can hack into windows process and manipulate memory (read / write).

what's the use case?

Comment: Well, cheats for games are usually made in c++. It takes a long time to code, is really complicated and overall a big hassle. Pymem allows you to do virtually all of what you can in c++ with memory manipulation. But, python is insanely popular, so every anticheat has a fix for it, and python is really slow so its hard to make good performant cheats with it. Julia has basically the same syntax as python but is also super fast. So you would be able to write crazy complex and performant cheats, relatively quick and easy.

Comment: I would love that all Julia packages would have such a clear, beginner friendly, doc. You may have cross one of the few issues with Julia: the community of windows gamers hacking with Julia may not (yet) being so strong...